# How can I find elements of a MongoDB collection that are taking up a large amount of space?

Tags: mongodb, collections, size, diskspace

If I have a collection with thousands of elements, is there a way I can easily find which elements are taking up the most space (in terms of MB)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no built-in query for this, you have to iterate the collection, gather size for each document, and sort afterwards. Here's how it'd work:

```
var cursor = db.coll.find(); 
var doc_size = {}; 
cursor.forEach(function (x) { 
    var size = Object.bsonsize(x); 
    doc_size[x._id] = size;
});
```

At this point you'll have a hashmap with document ids as keys and their sizes as values. 
Note that with this approach you will be fetching the entire collection over the wire. An alternative is to use MapReduce and do this server-side (inside mongo):

```
> function mapper() {emit(this._id, Object.bsonsize(this));}
> function reducer(obj, size_in_b) { return { id : obj, size : size_in_b}; }
>
> var results = db.coll.mapReduce(mapper, reducer, {out : {inline : 1 }}).results
> results.sort(function(r1, r2) { return r2.value - r1.value; })
```

inline:1 tells mongo not to create a temporary collection for results, everything will be kept in RAM.

And a sample output from one of my collections:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("4ce9339942a812be22560634"),
        "value" : 1156115
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("4ce9340442a812be24560634"),
        "value" : 913413
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("4ce9340642a812be26560634"),
        "value" : 866833
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("4ce9340842a812be28560634"),
        "value" : 483614
    },
       ...
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("4ce9340742a812be27560634"),
        "value" : 61268
    }
]
>
```

Comment: I don't think I want to build a huge in-memory array

Comment: a huge array of few thousands elements? how much memory is required for a 10K hash map with numbers as keys and values?

Comment: and you don't have to keep all of them, you can modify the code to keep top N biggest ones.

Comment: good point about the in memory hash map, although I did a modified version saving to a collection and that allows sorting etc.  Thanks though!

Comment: you can also try with map reduce, have a look at the answer again

Comment: Nice, ok I like it more than what I arrived at and will accept your answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out!  I did this in two steps using [Object.bsonsize()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/dbshell+Reference#dbshellReference-Miscellaneous):

```
db.myCollection.find().forEach(function(myObject) {
    db.objectSizes.save({object_id: object._id, size: Object.bsonsize(chain)});
});

db.objectSizes.find().sort({size: -1}).limit(5).pretty();
```